# YCSB: Create flexible schema on MySQL

Tags: mysql, ycsb

I'm trying to benchmark a MySQL database with YCSB (https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB) but I'm struggling with this line on the documentation:

For CoreWorkload, the YCSB Client will assume that there is a "table" called "usertable" with a flexible schema: columns can be added at runtime as desired.

But how do I do this on MySQL ? I can't find anywhere any instructions of how to create a flexible schema on MySQL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly true for relational databases, such as MySQL. For these you should create the table with the exact number of columns needed for YCSB.

The `JDBCClient` class must give you a hint for something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE usertable 
(
  YCSB_KEY VARCHAR(100),
  FIELD1 VARCHAR(100), FIELD2 VARCHAR(100),
  FIELD3 VARCHAR(100), FIELD4 VARCHAR(100),
  FIELD5 VARCHAR(100), FIELD6 VARCHAR(100),
  FIELD7 VARCHAR(100), FIELD8 VARCHAR(100),
  FIELD9 VARCHAR(100), FIELD10 VARCHAR(100),

} PRIMARY KEY (YCSB_KEY);
```

This is actually for another database but you can adjust for specific MySQL syntax easily.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle allows adding a column at runtime on Production Systems.

I think the syntax is along the lines of ALTER TABLE.

I am sure other database systems also allow modification of Tables- but not when the table is in use.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE usertable 
(
  YCSB_KEY VARCHAR(100),
  FIELD1 VARCHAR(100), FIELD2 VARCHAR(100),


} PRIMARY KEY (YCSB_KEY);
```

`ALTER TABLE usertable (....` this will change the table to have more fields, indexes and so on.